# WPF StackPanel to make the elements' width to be related each other

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, controls, stackpanel

*I'm very new in WPF*

In my code, there is a **StackPanel** and it has 3 children controls.

```
<StackPanel Background="Green" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock Width="200">
    <TextBlock Width=???>
    <TextBlock Width="200>
</StackPanel>
```

The First and Third TextBlocks have already their Width, 
but I want to make a Second TextBlock's Width to be dependent on Window's size.
it means if Window's Width is **1000** - the 2nd TextBlock's Width should be **600**.
Probably I should use some **Binding**, but I'm not sure.

I appreciate your help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace the `StackPanel` with a `Panel` that resizes its children, like for example a `Grid`:

```
<Grid Background="Green">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" />
</Grid>
```